# Unnecessary value concatenation and Type Errors in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA code takes a .txt file from a specific software output (Carlson Survey software) and does some calculations, then converts it into a .CSV file.  I am specifically having issues with the calculation component, where one of my columns of the text file (brought into excel using comma separators) isn't doing the calculation I tell it, and is seemingly concatenating itself (removes everything after the decimal point).  My assumption is, that because I am taking these values into an Array (which had to be set as string, or else I was getting type errors) which is set as a string, this is causing the concatenation after the decimal point.  I am at a loss as to why the calculation doesn't appear to be running though, as the program seemingly executes fine.

And the VBA script for quick reference (specific section with problem is the 'Do data conversion' section:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Choose and open the .TXT file for conversion
Dim answer As Integer
answer = MsgBox("Do you want to process a .TXT file for use in InfoSWMM?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Select .TXT File")
If answer = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim Ret
Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt")
If Ret <> False Then
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Range("$A$1") _
        )
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End If
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Do data conversion, SECTION NEEDS UPDATING LACKING FEATURES, BUGS
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim tester(3) As String 'Bug[1] related, type error (see below).  String type fixes type error, but causes undesired concatenation
Dim col_test As Integer
Dim rim As Integer

For row = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value) = True Then
        Exit For
    End If
    'Change these values in case feature code library is changed in Carlson, also need to add extra fields
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value = "SD" Or ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 5).Value = "WQ" Then
        col_test = 20
        rim = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 4).Value
        For i = 0 To 3
            tester(i) = ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col_test).Value 'Bug[1] here, type error if not a String.
            col_test = col_test + 4
        Next i
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 37).Value = rim - Application.Max(tester) 'Bug[2] here, not performing calculation.
    End If
Next row
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Save converted file as .CSV
MsgBox "Choose the desired save location for the .CSV file."
Dim InitialName As String
Dim PathName As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
InitialName = "sfm_output"
PathName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, fileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv")
ws.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathName, _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
MsgBox "Process completed successfully." & vbNewLine & "File saved to:" & vbNewLine & PathName
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Close all Workbooks
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like your worksheet contains errors. A cell that contains an error value will be `Variant/Error` - you should verify with `IsError` whether that's the case, *before* you try to treat that error value as a string or number. `CStr` against a `Variant/Error` will probably not yield the result you're expecting. Also always validate with `IsNumeric` before doing math against values taken from a worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried CSTRING or CINT functions?

For example:
tester(i) = CString(ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col_test).Value)

Comment: I tried CInt, and then it threw a type mismatch error.  However, because of your answer I looked up CInt and found that Val() does something similar.  Using Val fixed the concatenation and type error issue.

The second issue with the calculation not performing is due to my lack of observation, as I failed to notice those values in that row actually contain some text in them so the subtraction doesnt make sense.  Im fixing that part now, thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like the real problem is lack of validation. See what `IsError` and `IsNumeric` can do for you given any `Variant` value.